# Cannot write event log to the designated log

Tags: c#, event-log

I try to write new log to MyLog but it always writes to Application Log (Windows Log)

```
 string sSource;
 string sLog;
 sSource = "MySource";
 sLog = "MyLog";
 if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
     EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);
 using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(sLog))
 {
     eventLog.Source = sSource;
     eventLog.WriteEntry("Log message example", EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
 }
```

I tried to delete the log entry on Registry to recreate the log but the problem still persists.

Ty any help.

Answer (score 0):

I use nearly the same code, with two differences. I set the log manually not in the constructor and I don't give a category on the `WriteEntry` method:

```
    string sSource;
    string sLog;
    sSource = "MySource";
    sLog = "MyLog";
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);
    using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog())
    {
        eventLog.Source = sSource;
        eventLog.Log = sLog;
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Log message example", EventLogEntryType.Information, 101);
    }
```

Comment: It stills save to Application Log, really strange.

Comment: Somebody had a simmilar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114998/eventlog-logs-in-application-even-though-set-to-another-log

Comment: Thanks, I have to reboot the machine to get it remap. Really messy system.